# Erro ao obter foto de amigo do facebook via SDK PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook, facebook-sdk

Estou usando a API do Facebook SDK para trabalhar com o facebook. A versão do SDK que estou usando é 2.8. Estou puxando a lista das IDs dos meus amigos e consigo obter com sucesso.

O que preciso agora é obter a foto de cada um deles, mas não estou conseguindo. Ele ao invés de retornar a foto ele me retorna uma foto com "?" (interrogação). Quando não retorna isso, ele retorna geralmente com a mensagem de erro abaixo:

> (#12) picture edge for this type is deprecated for versions v2.3 and
>   higher

Já tentei de tudo, mas nada adiantou. Estava tentando assim:

https://graph.facebook.com/745290582220378/picture?type=normal **=>** Não adiantou, retorna interrogação.

https://graph.facebook.com/745290582220378/picture?type=normal&access_token=TOKEN_DE_ACESSO_GERADO **=>** Não adiantou retorna o erro acima citado **(#12) picture edge for this...**

No meu código PHP usei

```
$this->facebook->request('get', '/'.$FriendID.'/picture?type=large');
```

Mas deu o erro citado acima.

Não sei o que fazer e preciso entregar para o cliente, mas não sei como resolver.

Comment: acesse do seu app a url https://graph.facebook.com/745290582220378 e veja o que ela retorna

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo ele pede o token e se eu coloco o token ele me retorna a ID do amigo somente, nada a mais.

Comment: verifique se seu aplicativo cadastrado no facebook está marcado como aplicativo desktop, se tiver, altere para app web.

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo está para web já

Comment: estranho , voce tem permissões suficiente?

Comment: Sim, estou pedindo permissão de Lista de Amigos, Perfil publico e Publicação no mural

Answer (score 0):

Eu tentei aqui e aconteceu o seguinte:
Acessei https://graph.facebook.com/745290582220378/picture?type=normal&access_token=... e obtive o erro

> (#12) picture edge for this type is deprecated for versions v2.3 and higher

ao acessar apenas https://graph.facebook.com/745290582220378?access_token=..., obtive a mensagem:

> Object with ID '745290582220378' does not exist

O que significa que esse id não corresponde a nenhum usuário do Facebook.
Tentei novamente usando meu id do Facebook e o primeiro link funcionou perfeitamente. Então acredito que há algum erro na sua obtenção do id dos usuários.

Comment: o código do meu ID que consigo também pegar com o script ele gera a imagem certinho, mas as do meus amigo não, isso que é estranho

Answer (score 0):

Fiz uns testes no GraphApi Explorer no Facebook e o código gerado foi:

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
  accessToken,
  new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
      // Insert your code here
    }
});

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,picture,friends{picture,first_name,last_name}");
request.setParameters(parameters);

    request.executeAsync();
```

Veja que o endereço das fotos dos amigos estão em friends>picture. Aqui consegui ver todas as fotos. Veja se você consegue adaptar para seu projeto.